# How to connect PostgreSQL Azure Cloud Server with SQL Developer?

Tags: postgresql, azure, ide, connection

Does anyone know if there is any chance to connect a PostgreSQL Azure Cloud Server with  SQLDeveloper?
If someone knows this may you could explain to me how it works.
Or if it doesn't work which IDE should I use for it?
Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: To my knowledge SQLDeveloper is an Oracle product that supports only Oracle databases. For PostgreSQL you have many options, please check the wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients

Comment: Use Azure Data Studio to connect to PostgreSQL. Refer this Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-postgres?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect azure PostgreSQL database using Azure Data Studio. I tried to repro this and below are the steps to connect using ADS.

- Install **Azure Data Studio** and Click extensions on ADS and install PostgreSQL.

[image]

- Click on Connections and in servers, click new connection.

[image]

- Set Connection type to **PostgreSQL** and enter the connection details like Server name, username and password. Click connect.
  [image]

[image]

Azure PostgreSQL DB is connected using Azure Data Studio.

Reference: **MS document** [Quickstart: Connect and query PostgreSQL - Azure Data Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-postgres?view=sql-server-ver16)